# What is the python3 alternative to the apply method in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a legacy piece of code that I'm upgrading to python3 but I've been stuck on the alternative of the [apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) python2 function that was dropped in python2.3 and replaced with `function` however `function` isn't working in python 3.8 Is there an alternative to this function?

I have `return apply(fn, args, kwargs)`
I have tried
`return function(fn, args, kwargs)`

but in both cases I'm getting a `NameError`

Comment: `return fn(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: You're misunderstanding what it's been replaced by. Not the "`function` function", but simply `fn(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: I still get Here is what I get

`>>> fn(*args, **kwargs)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`NameError: name 'fn' is not defined`

Comment: `fn` is **the function you're trying to call!** You're giving us an example of "`apply(fn, ...)`", so we're telling you it's `fn(...)`. Whatever that function is called in your actual code we don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `fn(*args, **kwargs)` should solve your problem